# Tor transparent IPv6 destination_from_socket(): Bug

Tags: transparent-proxy, ipv6

Configuration file torrc

```
User root
PidFile /opt/var/run/tor.pid
#Log info file /opt/var/log/tor.log
Log notice file /opt/var/log/tor.log
ExcludeExitNodes {RU},{UA},{AM},{KG},{BY}
StrictNodes 1
TransPort 192.168.97.97:9151
TransPort [::]:9151
ExitRelay 0
GeoIPFile /opt/share/tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /opt/share/tor/geoip6
DataDirectory /opt/var/lib/tor
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6 [fc00::]/7
DNSPort 127.0.0.1:9153
DNSPort [::1]:9153
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
ClientUseIPv4 0
ClientUseIPv6 1
```

I start `curl -6 -v http://www.flibustahezeous3.onion/` and get an error

```
Nov 18 01:04:06.000 [notice] Tor 0.4.1.6 opening new log file.
Nov 18 01:04:06.589 [notice] Tor 0.4.1.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.8-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.

Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:9153
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opened DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:9153
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opening DNS listener on [::1]:9153
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opened DNS listener on [::1]:9153
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 192.168.97.97:9151
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 192.168.97.97:9151
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on [::]:9151
Nov 18 01:08:27.257 [notice] Opened Transparent pf/netfilter listener on [::]:9151
Nov 18 01:08:38.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done

Nov 18 10:23:58.000 [warn] destination_from_socket(): Bug: Received transparent data from an unsuported socket family 10 (on Tor 0.4.1.6 )
Nov 18 10:23:58.000 [warn] Fetching original destination failed. Closing.
```

How to fix?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you running torsocks with your curl command?

Comment: Yes. Redirecting traffic to the port 9151 goes through ip6tables. 
> `ip6tables  -t filter  -A INPUT       -p tcp  --dport 9040      -j ACCEPT`
> `ip6tables  -t nat     -A PREROUTING  -p tcp  -d fc00::/7       -j REDIRECT --to-port 9151`
> `ip6tables  -t nat     -A OUTPUT      -p tcp  -d fc00::/7       -j REDIRECT --to-port 9151`

Comment: No, my question is have you tried running the command, "torsocks curl -6 -v http://www.flibustahezeous3.onion/"

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find a package with torsocks for my router. Ipv4 is works.

Comment: My suggestion is to put in a bug report. Go to https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor, create an account, and click on "Create a Ticket" to put in a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Tor binary wasn't built with [`TRANS_NETFILTER_IPV6` defined](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/src/core/or/connection_edge.c#n2572).